# What is the variable that holds the My Cart url?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have edited XML files to add an icon before the My Cart top-link. I made the icon a link as well, but I added a simple ....

I am looking to instead use Magento's variable that holds My Cart's URL in case my store's URL changes.

I am looking for something like this:

```
<a href="<?php $_myCartLink ?>">...</a>
```

with the correct My Cart Link variable.

Thank you!

```
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"', '<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');?>"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> </a>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are looking for is

```
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"', '<a href="'.Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart').'"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> </a>');
```

...I think

Comment: You have saved me three times today my friend!

Comment: What exactly does the '. and .' do?

Comment: The dot is used to concatenate strings. It's basic PHP.

Comment: I'm still very new to Object Oriented languages but I trying my best to learn as I go! Thanks for your help, today is turning out to be a great day!

Answer (score 3):

To get a url from the frontend phtml file (which your example seems to be hinting at):

`<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');?>`

If you want to get the url from a controller use:

`$this->getUrl('checkout/cart')`

Comment: Please see my edit above for reference. I tried your first example in my local Links.php file but I get an error:  unexpected T_STRING.  Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is with the quotes!